# Unit testing customer membership provider with VS2010 testing project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to test my custom membership provider using MSTest in VS2010, but keep getting an error `System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'TafAdris.Security.TafAdrisMembershipProvider' from assembly 'TafAdrisSecurity'.`

After a lot of struggling, I realized that MSTest cannot find my assembly even though I specified Copy Local in the References folder. Next I tried debugging the unit test and in the Watch window I type Environment.CurrentDirectory. I get the following folder:

`C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CustomSecurityProviderApp\TestResults\XYZ_PCNAME 2011-10-11 18_24_55\Out`

But the Test project output folder is specified in a totally different location. Has anyone had a similar issue? Do you know how to force MSTest to load DLL from a specific location?

I tried specifying additional folders in Test Settings -> Unit Test but that seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved this. This is the solution:

```
[AssemblyInitialize]
public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
{
    System.Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CustomSecurityProviderApp\CustomMembership.Test\bin\Debug";
}
```

This caused test to run in the specified directory where my custom membership is located.